# Can't call VBA built in function with Application.Run

Tags: vba, higher-order-functions

In VBA a user defined subroutine or function can be called using the `Application.Run` method like so

```
Application.Run "macroName", arg1 ', ...
```

allowing for a crude simulation of delegates in VBA.
However, built-in VBA functions cannot be called the same way

```
' Error 1004: Cannot run macro 'FileDateTime'. The macro may not be available ...
Debug.Print Application.Run("FileDateTime", "<some file path>")
```

Given the string of a built-in functions name *e.g.* "FileDateTime", how can that function be called?

One work-around would be to create functions that merely return the result of the built-in function.  But I am looking for a more direct solution.

Comment: Your best bet would be to wrap the underlying function in a class method and use `CallByName(inst, "MethodName" ...)`

Comment: I don't see the benefit of defining a class over just defining a copy of the function I need e.g. `FileDateTime_`.  It just seems like two wrappers instead of just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need Application.run for this (and usage was incorrect as well):

```
Debug.Print FileDateTime("some file path")
```

EDIT:  An alternative is to write your own macro:

```
function F_D_T(path as string)  
F_D_T = FileDateTime("somepath")  
end function
```

and call this macro using application.run

Comment: See Edit: I am trying to use `Application.Run` for a crude implementation of delegates.  And please elaborate as why usage was incorrect as well.

Comment: std is just some module. I posted some raw code.  I will trim the example down as necessary.

Comment: it looks to me you're trying to apply VB.net to vba...I could be wrong.  For example, what is your expected result with the following line: files_mtimes = std.Mapped("FileDateTime", file_array) ?

Comment: hopefully the example is simple enough now.

Comment: I don't think it's possible - you can simulate a built-in function with macro but not the other way around.  When you use the built-in function you will need to follow its rule (parameter / usage).  Long in short, application.run works only with macro not built-in function =(