# Executing global functions in VBA fails with "Object Doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, activex, ms-word

I'm trying to execute a string commands using `Application.Run`

Given the example:

`Application.Run "MsgBox", "bla bla"`

Regardless to my efforts, i keep receiving:

`Object Doesn't support this property or method`

Additional information:

1. I'm running from word macro
2. I must support this kind of functionality; dynamically loading and executing certain functions.

Comment: There's no built-in facility for this: best you could do is create a class with wrapper methods for the built-in methods you want to call and maybe use CallbyName on an instance of that class.  Use use VBE automation to dynamically write a method and call that.  There's typically a "better" approach to this kind of thing though.

Comment: But what is the difference between calling my own functions and VB's runtime functions?

Comment: The difference is you can't use `Application.Run` to call built-in functions. It's just not supported. Previous similar Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386827/cant-call-vba-built-in-function-with-application-run

Comment: And sort-of related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036711/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-constant-into-a-constant/10037332#10037332